# How to change all the url from the html

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to add localhost at the beginning of the all the URL of any web page,
I have created simple node js get request and fetched all the data, now I want find all the a href and need to replace all the URLs with localhost

here is my code in nodejs

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = 4000;
var https = require("https");
var absolutify = require('absolutify')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let link_url = req.query.url;

    https.get(link_url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        const control = async _ => {
            const numApples = await updateLinksInHTML(data);
            return numApples;
          }
        control().then(function(t){
            res.send(t);
        });
    });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
})

function updateLinksInHTML(html) {
    let regex = /[^<]*(<a.*?href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>)/g;
    var link,hrml1;
    html1 = html;
    while((link = regex.exec(html1)) !== null) {
        count++;
        let a = "localhost:4000/?url=" + link[2];
        html1 = html1.replace(link[2], a);
    }
    return html1;
  }

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Proxy server running on ${port}!`))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of error you're getting ?

Comment: It this code just replace only first occurrence of url

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a method, maybe it will help you solve your problem. Use regex with advanced usage of [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

Your util function will become:

```
function updateLinksInHTML(html) {
  return html.replace(/href="(.*?)"/g, (match, $1) => { // g flag to replace all links
    return 'href="localhost:4000/?url=' + $1 + '"'; // return the string with your format
  })
}
```

`updateLinksInHTML` just is a normal sync function, you do not need the `await` keyword,

then finally, your code will to be like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let link_url = req.query.url;

  https.get(link_url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
      const resultString = updateLinksInHTML(data); // updateLinksInHTML just return a string not Promise<string>
      res.send(resultString);
    });

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
})

function updateLinksInHTML(html) {
  return html.replace(/href="(.*?)"/g, (match, $1) => { // g flag to replace all links
    return 'href="localhost:4000/?url=' + $1 + '"'; // return the string with your format
  })
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Proxy server running on ${port}!`))
```

Comment: @javascript what is `work as well ` and `not work as well `?